# CakePHP Login Redirect Bug

Tags: php, cakephp

I have built a very simple CakePHP website using the Auth component and have stumbled across a very annoying bug. Basically if a user tries to access an area that they are required to login to first they are taken to a login page and then sent back to the original page if they successfully login... this is all fine and dandy but because this remembrance of where the user tried to go is stored in a session it hangs around so if I ended up at the login page then decided to go elsewhere then comeback and then GO DIRECT to the login form it will send me to the page I tried to access earlier on as it's still being stored in the session.

How do I stop this? As it means users are being sent to random pages when they login from the login page if they tried to access the site previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug.  This is intended, documented behavior.

Fortunately, CakePHP is well documented.  Can check out the 1.3 book that details the variables needed to [change default Auth behavior, specifically `$this->Auth->autoRedirect` property](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1274/autoRedirect).

Comment: If I set that to `false` though I open up more worms because I will then have to manually set the redirect in the login method but the issue is that I want it to redirect the user to the previous page BUT only if they have come from a previous page and NOT if they are just visiting the login page and HAVE been browsing the site earlier as described in OP. Cheers

Comment: @Cameron What exactly are you wanting to happen when the user hits the login page after leaving and is still logged in?

Comment: Well they wouldn't be logged in as they never logged in the first place. What I want is to send the user to the page they are trying to access BUT not remember this in the session if they decide not to login and then return later.

Comment: Ah, this sounds more like a job for persistent data on the client side.  If they never login you have no real way to assign the URL they were at in way that you can later retrieve it.  Sounds like you need [cookies](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1280/Cookies)

Comment: But why does the Session stick around if they leave the login page? As when they login in later they will be taken to a place they have requested in the past and not the present.

Comment: Because PHP sessions do that.  Open up a blank PHP file.  Put `session_start();` at the top.  Add a variable to the `$_SESSION` array and then `echo` it out.  Close the browser completely.  Come back to that page.  Chances are if it was within a couple minutes that same variable will print out.  Check out [`$this->Session->destroy()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1311/Methods)

Comment: Okay how would I destroy the session if the user LEAVES the login page!